# The error of NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I add a NSTimer in the iphone application。When I run the application，it‘s failed。I have tracked it and found that it stop at “0x3050c3ad  <+0013>  call   0x306aeaa5 ” and cann't go on in Debugger。

If you know，please tell me what’s wrong with the application and how to solve it。

Thank you！

The code is：

```
NSTimer *m_heartBeatTimer;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *m_heartBeatTimer;

@synthesize m_heartBeatTimer;


-(void)HeartBeatTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{

  [csocket CloseSocket];

}

case PING:
        {
            [self SendDataToServer:"00" Type:PONG];

            if(m_heartBeatTimer != nil)
                [m_heartBeatTimer invalidate];
            m_heartBeatTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(HeartBeatTimer:) userInfo:nil 
                                                               repeats:NO];


        } break;
```

Comment: I don't think anyone's going to be able to help you based on that information alone (considering we don't know what `0x306aeaa5` is). Can you post your code and tell us what the exact problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lqf,

First you should access the timer via `self.m_heartBeatTimer` since you declared it as retained in the `@property` declaration.  If you don't use the `self.` prefix, you aren't using the setter and therefore you aren't retaining the timer like you specified in the `@property` declaration.

I have no clue what your obscure error message is, but I'm guessing it's memory related.  Make sure you use that `self.` prefix and let me know if that works.  If you actually had an error message of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` output on the Run Console, please update your post with that so it's something people can work with.

-Rob

Comment: Rob，
the problem is that I do “[m_heartBeatTimer invalidate];” twice。
One is "if(m_heartBeatTimer != nil) [m_heartBeatTimer invalidate];",other is "[m_heartBeatTimer invalidate];" at front.
I changed "[m_heartBeatTimer invalidate];" to "[m_heartBeatTimer invalidate]; m_heartBeatTimer=nil" and it's ok.
Thank you for the same!
Could you tell me how to close questions?

Comment: lqf, you should still use the `self.` prefix so the setter gets called and the timer is retained.  Otherwise it will get created as an autorelease which defeats the purpose of you declaring it as a retained property in the original declaration.